# Why is there only adrenoreceptors and no active adrenergic innervation in bronchus and uterus?

Tags: pharmacology, receptor, pharmacodynamics, autonomic-nervous-system

Our bronchus and uterus has beta adrenoreceptors, but they have no active sympathetic nervous system innervation in these organs. Was there a sympathetic innervation in trachea and uterus, earlier, that we lost it during the course of evolution, if no, why did nature gives us only adrenergic receptors and no adrenergic nerves in trachea and uterus?

Comment: If endocrine system is an alternate signalling system to nervous system. Epinephrine and Norepinephrine have endocrine roles as well apart from being neurotransmitters. In fact I had learnt about their endocrine function long before I realized that they also act as neurotransmitters.